# Error getting the output of child process in node

Tags: node.js, stdout, child-process

I have a c program (I didn't code it) that prints some data in the terminal. I launch the program as a child process in node with the spawn function.

```
const child_process = spawn('./myProgram', ['--arg']);
```

After that, I code the event to get the printed data:

```
child_process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

When I run the program I can't see the output data from my c program in my nodejs terminal. If I initialize the child process with stdio as inherit it works.

```
const child_process = spawn('./myProgram', ['--arg'], {stdio :'inherit'});
```

The key point here is that I need to process that data in my nodejs app. I suppose the way the c file prints the data is not the standard one, so my nodjs program does not get it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `child_process.stdout.on(...)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed out typing the question.

Comment: Does this work with other programs? A simple test is like `spawn('ls')`.

Comment: Another thing to check is that you're not getting any errors, or that it's not outputting to `stderr` instead.

Comment: It works. The problem is with that c program. I have also created my own c program to test it and works.

Comment: Remember there's both STDOUT and STDERR, there's *two* output streams. Check both. They will look the same in a terminal, but `program > /dev/null` will suppress just STDOUT.

Comment: @tadman You are right. It was outputting to the 'stderr'. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file was outputting to `stderr` instead to `stdout`. It was fixed by adding the event to `stderr`:

```
child_process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

[@tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) got the answere.